# Image not access in iOS 6 from document library?

Tags: ios

I have to access image from document library in iOS 6 .

```
strImgSign = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents//%@", NSHomeDirectory(),strImgSign];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    NSString *strImgSign = [[arrNameFinal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"signimage"];
    /var/mobile/Applications/D912ACC0-5B23-49B2-B9F1-E45ECD713553/Documents//docSign6167Feb13,2015-12.03.26.png
```

But image access in iOS 7,8 is perfect Working.

Answer (score 1):

You should not build the directory from the `NSHoneDirectory` or use path separators in you string.

Correct way to build directories:

```
NSString *imagePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
imagePath = [imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:strImgSign];
```

But even better and **only correct way** is to use the correct directory:

```
NSString *documentPath =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
NSString *imagePath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:strImgSign];
```

Comment: not working but i have to use @"docSign6167Feb13,2015-12.03.26.png" its work but  NSString *strImgSign = [[arrNameFinal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"signimage"] are not work..

Comment: What do you mean not working? The code is correct for getting the path to the documents directory. The `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` is the correct way of adding files to the path.

Comment: Well the code in my answer is correct, please list the output of the `imagePath` variable.

Comment: Post your code, error and what not. Just saying it's not working is not telling us anything. I you want help you need to tell what you are doing, what is going wrong and what you did to fix it.

Comment: Its Problem in iOS 6 :

Comment: if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
            UIImageView *imgSignlk;
            NSString *documentPath =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
            NSString *imagePath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[arrNameFinal objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"signimage"]];
            imgSignlk.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imagePath]

Comment: That code should just as well work in iOS 6. There is nothing in the code that will not working in iOS 6. You should search for your issue elsewhere,

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra `/` in your path:

```
strImgSign = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents//%@", NSHomeDirectory(),strImgSign];
```

Change that to:

```
strImgSign = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@", NSHomeDirectory(),strImgSign];
```

But as mentioned by @rckoenes, it's not the correct way of building file system paths. If your image is located in document directory you can use:

```
NSString *docDirectory  = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *yourImagePath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:strImgSign];
```

But I'm not sure how it worked for you in iOS 7 and iOS 8

Comment: You really don't want to build you path's like this, use `stringByAppendingPathComponent:`. And  you should not use the correct way to get the documents directory.

Comment: @rckoenes: I just used OP's code. I'll edit my answer with correct approach.

Answer (score -1):

NSString *filename = [filepart lastObject];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString* inboxPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Inbox"];
    NSString *filePath = [inboxPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];